# Elasticsearch / Marvel search rate

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

How is the elasticsearch search rate (displayed in Marvel) calculated? We can see a search rate of about 1700 - 2000 per second but we measure that our applications are sending about 500 - 600 search request per second to our elastic search cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question before and posted on Marvel forum, but no one answered me.

Later I found it out by the observation that when the number of shards of an index changes the search rate changes as well. We only have one index for search right now, and when there is a single shard, the search rate is almost the same as the requests we send to ES cluster. When we have 10 shards, it's 10 times the actual number of requests.

So, I believe:

1. Search Rate is actually the search requests happens on all shards per second
2. Search Latency is the latency within each shard

More details are in [this post](http://blog.kiyanpro.com/2016/04/15/elasticsearch/Marvel-What-Does-Search-Rate-Mean/)

Answer (score 0):

there is no a official doc said it's meaning, but in my experience, if you have 10 shards, the search rates in kibana is 10 times the actual number of requests, just like free tymekiyan said.